# Registry Duplicate Key

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry

So I am writing one of my first large batch scripts and part of the script needs to create several keys in the registry.  The problem I am having is that a redundant subordinate key is being created in the path and I am not sure how to solve it.  Also of note is that this only occurs on certain systems and is not always the case.

Here is the command I am using:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Riedel\ARTIST SNMP Agent" /v "MasterSnmpAgentIpAddr" /t REG_SZ /d "127.0.0.1:705"
```

When I look in the registry to see the result, here is the path that it is placed in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Wow6432Node\Riedel\ARTIST SNMP Agent
```

I've tried a few methods of creating registry keys, but they yield the same results.  Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: does it happen when you use a hard-coded.reg file imported like this `Regedit /S regfile.reg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wow6432Node` is for the 32bit programs in 64bit OS. So you should better use the `reg add` switch `/reg:`
try this for 32bit entries

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Riedel\ARTIST SNMP Agent" /v "MasterSnmpAgentIpAddr" /t REG_SZ /d "127.0.0.1:705" /reg:32
```

and for 64bit

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Riedel\ARTIST SNMP Agent" /v "MasterSnmpAgentIpAddr" /t REG_SZ /d "127.0.0.1:705" /reg:64
```

Comment: Thanks @Endoro !  Updated the line with the /reg:32 tag and it works as expected.  I really appreciate your help!